# Have menu open on current link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a menu that goes 4 to 5 levels deep. In most cases, selecting the menu will open up the same. Here is some html:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="trigger">Click Here</div>
   <div class="menu">
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a href="blah.aspx">Main</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                   <a href="blah1.aspx">First</a>
                   <ul>
                      <li>
                          <a href="blah3.aspx">Third</a>
                          <ul>
                              <li>
                                 <a href="blah5.aspx">Five</a>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                 <a href="blah6.aspx">Six</a>
                              </li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="blah4.aspx">Fourth</a>
                      </li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href="blah2.aspx">Second</a>
                </li>
           </ul>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it so that if you click on "Third", and you go to that page, that when you get to that page and click on the menu again, that it will open up showing the "Third" title at the top with its children instead of opening it up like it would normally do?

Answer (score 1):

If the page is loaded (after kicking a link)

you need to indicate first which page has been loaded for example: blah3.aspx or blah4.aspx

Then in Order to **rearange** the list, u must get the html content of the list-item that should be shown on top menu.

```
<div class="menu">
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a href="blah.aspx">Main</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                   <a href="blah1.aspx">First</a>
                   <ul>
                      <li id="page3">
                          <a href="blah3.aspx">Third</a>
                          <ul>
                              <li>
                                 <a href="blah5.aspx">Five</a>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                 <a href="blah6.aspx">Six</a>
                              </li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="blah4.aspx">Fourth</a>
                      </li>
                   </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                   <a href="blah2.aspx">Second</a>
                </li>
           </ul>
      </ul>
   </div>
```

Example here if page 3 has been loaded:

Get inner html content:

```
var treeStructure = $("#page3").html;
```

Remove the list-item from list with the [jQuery remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method:

```
$("#page3").remove();
```

Add saved content to the beginning of the list with the [jQuery prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) method:

```
$(".menu ul").prepend("<li>" + treeStructure + "</li>");
```